# Table by row with R

Tags: r, apply

I would like to tabulate by row within a data frame.  I can obtain adequate results using `table` within `apply` in the following example:

```
df.1 <- read.table(text = '
  state  county  city  year1  year2  year3  year4  year5
      1       2     4      0      0      0      1      2
      2       5     3     10     20     10     NA     10
      2       7     1    200    200     NA     NA    200
      3       1     1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
', na.strings = "NA", header=TRUE)

tdf <- t(df.1)
apply(tdf[4:nrow(tdf),1:nrow(df.1)], 2, function(x) {table(x, useNA = "ifany")})
```

Here are the results:

```
[[1]]
x
0 1 2 
3 1 1 

[[2]]
x
  10   20 <NA> 
   3    1    1 

[[3]]
x
 200 <NA> 
   3    2 

[[4]]
x
<NA> 
   5
```

However, in the following example each row consists of a single value.

```
df.2 <- read.table(text = '
  state  county  city  year1  year2  year3  year4  year5
      1       2     4      0      0      0      0      0
      2       5     3      1      1      1      1      1
      2       7     1      2      2      2      2      2
      3       1     1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
', na.strings = "NA", header=TRUE)

tdf.2 <- t(df.2)
apply(tdf.2[4:nrow(tdf.2),1:nrow(df.2)], 2, function(x) {table(x, useNA = "ifany")})
```

The output I obtain is:

```
# [1] 5 5 5 5
```

As such, I cannot tell from this output that the first 5 is for 0, the second 5 is for 1, the third 5 is for 2 and the last 5 is for NA.  Is there a way I can have R return the value represented by each 5 in the second example?

Comment: You could also look into reshaping the data (from wide to long) before using `table`. There are many ways to do this, I guess. Then you could create a `cityid` column as `paste(state,county,city,sep=".")` and run `table(df$cityid,df$year)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `table` solution:

```
table(
    rep(rownames(df.1),5),
    unlist(df.1[,4:8]),
    useNA="ifany")
```

This gives

```
    0 1 2 10 20 200 <NA>
  1 3 1 1  0  0   0    0
  2 0 0 0  3  1   0    1
  3 0 0 0  0  0   3    2
  4 0 0 0  0  0   0    5
```

...and for your `df.2`:

```
    0 1 2 <NA>
  1 5 0 0    0
  2 0 5 0    0
  3 0 0 5    0
  4 0 0 0    5
```

Well, this is a solution unless you really like having a list of tables for some reason.

Comment: I could give the checkmark to any of the answers.  However, I like this answer best even though it is least similar to the solution I had tried in my post.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `lapply` to systematically output a list. You would have to loop over the row indices:

```
sub.df <- as.matrix(df.2[grepl("year", names(df.2))])
lapply(seq_len(nrow(sub.df)), 
       function(i)table(sub.df[i, ], useNA = "ifany"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Protect the result by wrapping with `list`:

```
apply(tdf.2[4:nrow(tdf.2),1:nrow(df.2)], 2, 
              function(x) {list(table(x, useNA = "ifany")) })
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is stated in `apply`s help:

> ... If n equals 1, apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and
>   an array of dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise ...

The inconsistencies of the return values of base R's apply family is the reason why I shifted completely to `plyr`s **ply functions. So this works as desired:

```
library(plyr)
alply( df.2[ 4:8 ], 1, function(x) table( unlist(x), useNA = "ifany" ) )
```

Comment: +1 but let's not put everybody in the same basket: at least `lapply` and `vapply` provide consistent output formats.