# Count in buckets (Total by Row, aka Tabulate)

Tags: r

Imagine a group of three of machines (a,b,c) capture data in a series of tests. I need to count per test how many of each possible outcome has happened.

Using this test data and sample output, how might you solve it (assume that the test results may be numbers or alpha).

```
tests <- data.table(
  a = c(1,2,2,3,0),
  b = c(1,2,3,0,3),
  c = c(2,2,3,0,2)
)

sumry <- data.table(
  V0 = c(0,0,0,2,1),
  V1 = c(2,0,0,0,0),
  V2 = c(1,3,1,0,1),
  V3 = c(0,0,2,1,1),
  v4 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
)

tests
sumry
```

The output from sumry shows a column for each possible outcome/value (prefixed with V as in 'value' measured). Note: the sumry output indicates that there is the potential for a value of 4 but that is not observed in any of the test data here and therefore is always zero.

```
> tests
   a b c
1: 1 1 2
2: 2 2 2
3: 2 3 3
4: 3 0 0
5: 0 3 2

> sumry
   V0 V1 V2 V3 v4
1:  0  2  1  0  0
2:  0  0  3  0  0
3:  0  0  1  2  0
4:  2  0  0  1  0
5:  1  0  1  1  0
```

the V0 column from sumry indicates how many times the value zero is observed from any machine in test #1. For this set of test data zero is only observed in the 4th and 5th tests. The same holds true for V1-V4

I'm sure there's a simple name for this.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to tabulate by row.  If so, maybe one of the solutions here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825216/table-by-row-with-r/16825476?noredirect=1#16825476 Although, they might not return the column of `0`'s for `v4`.

Comment: I am not sure, but your code seems to return the answer you want.  If so, I am not sure what your question is.  If you are only asking for the term for what you are doing, I guess the term is `tabulate`.

Comment: hi mark, my code above is a static table that I created as an example of the output. If you note, its very clear that it should include both the zero and the 4 value (even though there is no four currently in the input). I tried to be very clear about what the output should be without offering a hypothesis (in order to not bias conversation).

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to emphasize that you want the `V4` included in the result.  Even still, the code you provide, if I remember correctly, returns the `V4`.  So, I suggest adding a second example in which your existing code does not return what you want.  Then someone will perhaps be able to provide code that does return the result you are after.

Comment: I am also confused that you accepted an existing answer that does not return the `V4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution built around `tabulate()`:

```
res <- suppressWarnings(do.call(rbind,apply(tests+1L,1L,tabulate)));
colnames(res) <- paste0('V',seq(0L,len=ncol(res)));
res;
##      V0 V1 V2 V3
## [1,]  0  2  1  0
## [2,]  0  0  3  0
## [3,]  0  0  1  2
## [4,]  2  0  0  1
## [5,]  1  0  1  1
```

Comment: works nicely. Thank you. :)

The absence of V4 is a bummer but I guess I could add a dummy row for each value to ensure it gets into the results and remove later.